# Can luis recognize city and country depending on build in geography intend?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Currently training my LUIS application. 
LUIS is connected with bing. LUIS has a lot of build in intents.

So, my question is:

Does the build in geography intent recognize city or country is my input and get the entity about?

For example:

forecast about georgia  -- this is country

forecast about munchen  -- this is city

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can differentiate [between cities, countries, or points of interest](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/LUIS-api/documentation/Pre-builtEntities) using the entity type:

```
{ "type": "builtin.geography.city", "entity": "paris" }
{ "type": "builtin.geography.country", "entity": "australia" }
{ "type": "builtin.geography.pointOfInterest", "entity": "sahara desert" }
```